# Weird bug in gedit - line numbers cut off on the left

Tags: virtualbox, gedit

gedit seems to have a bug - if the file has more than 9 lines, but less than 99, the line numbers get cut off on the left side. Does anyone have an an idea how to fix this?

[image: here's an example of this bug]

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 as a guest OS in VirtualBox.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The image you provided doesn't seem to illustrate the bug.

Comment: Sure it does, check numbers 10 through 15, the 1s are half cut on the left side

Comment: Now I see it :)

Comment: Hehe. No idea what it might be?

Comment: If this is a bug, then it is offtopic on Ask Ubuntu, and you should file a bug report.  However, this looks like it's already been reported.

Comment: Yeah, it has been reported. I tried googling for either the bug report or the solution and didn't come up with much. I thought maybe there was a simple margin fix that I could implement and decided to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/859560), and happens to me also on 12.04.2.

The problem seems to only happen when using a large font size (atleast with me). So to get around this you can either select a lower font size or use other monospaced font. In my system with "Ubuntu Mono" line numbers are shown correctly until size 30, while monospaced gets cropped at 24.

Comment: Hm yeah, good thinking. On my machine the left margin is messed up even with the Ubuntu font with a size as small as 15. Since I have a 1920x1200 screen I can't really go very small with font sizes as I can't see much. 

I guess I'll have to live with it :)